# Can we remove the scrollbars from the flag summary page by extending the height of the containers to match the content?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, flag-history

Rather than showing a scrollbar (as can be seen below),

[image]

Can we just extend the height of the element so it fits all the content? This is already done when you have many flagged items for the same post (as can be seen below).

[image]

I feel the scrollbars break the look and feel of the site.

**Miscellaneous Information**

**OS:** Windows 10

**Browser:** Chrome Version 62.0.3202.75 (Official Build) (64-bit)

**Extensions:** N/A (that would change the page design e.g. Postman, CORS Toggle etc.)

Comment: I don't see scroll bars on this page. What browser/OS are you using? Any user scripts/extensions installed?

Comment: @Oded added the information.

Comment: OK, updated my Chrome and can now see it. Need to figure out if it is us of them...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've updated our CSS — removing an `overflow: auto;` declaration seems to have sorted this out.

With you in the next build.

Comment: Any ideas when the next build will be?

Comment: Probably some time later today.