# Why am I being asked to log-in (or sign-up) while I'm already logged in?

Tags: support, bug, login

The title mostly says it all, this looks strange to me.

See the below screenshot:

[image]

So, I believe two contradictory scenarios happening here.

- I only should be seeing my user info (account summary, inbox notification) if i'm signed in.
- The pop-up box advises me to log in (or to create account) indicating I'm not logged in.

What's the play?

---

Notes: Browser: Chrome, Version 61.0.3163.100 (Official Build) (64-bit), Windows 10

Time of occurrence: 19:30 Indian time (GMT + 05:30).

Comment: Random logout on Chrome is [reported here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358345/has-anyone-else-been-logged-out-multiple-times-per-day-recently).  Do try another browser.

Comment: Meh - someone else blamed Chrome before I got here:(

Comment: This is not the first issue with Chrome (after the latest update) - see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358626/can-we-remove-the-scrollbars-from-the-flag-summary-page-by-extending-the-height) - I guess the new update has broken quite a bit.